# merge rows based on field value linux

Tags: python, linux, awk, merge

I'm trying to merge columns based on the value in the first field. I've tried using awk, but to no avail. Please see example input and output:

```
Input:  
10013   97      1503384  
10013   196     1506234  
10013   61      1507385  
10013   1559    1508385  
10014   1726    1514507  
10014   960     1519162  
10015   1920    1545535  
10015   124     1548915  
10015   77      1550284  

Desired_Output:  
10013   97,196,61,1559  1503384,1506234,1507385,1508385  
10014   1726,960        1514507,1519162  
10015   1920,124,77     1545535,1548915,1550284
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please use code tags for your Input(s) and scripts.

Comment: it always helps to post your script even if it's not working as desired.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest GNU **`datamash`** solution:

```
datamash -sW -g1 collapse 2 collapse 3 <file
```

- `-g1` - group by the 1st field
- `collapse N` - operation producing comma-separated list of all input values of the field `N` within each group

---

The output:

```
10013   97,196,61,1559  1503384,1506234,1507385,1508385
10014   1726,960    1514507,1519162
10015   1920,124,77 1545535,1548915,1550284
```

Comment: This looks like a very useful tool for these kind of tasks.

Comment: @karakfa, it's very convenient for simple grouping/aggregation and arithmetic operations. Recommended "stuff"

Comment: Just make sure that you have the most recent version - not all distribution repositories are up-to-date. See their [dowload page](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/download/).

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
$1 != f1 { if (NR>1) print f1, f2, f3; f1=f2=f3=s="" }
{ f1=$1; f2=f2 s $2; f3=f3 s $3; s="," }
END { print f1, f2, f3 }

$ awk -f tst.awk file | column -t
10013  97,196,61,1559  1503384,1506234,1507385,1508385
10014  1726,960        1514507,1519162
10015  1920,124,77     1545535,1548915,1550284
```

Comment: How do we tweak this for unknown number of columns?

Comment: @Naveed Write a loop? Post a new question with sample input/output if you'd like more help.

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '{f2[$1]=f2[$1] sep[$1] $2;                   # concatenate 2nd field 
        f3[$1]=f3[$1] sep[$1] $3;                   # concatenate 3rd field 
        sep[$1]=","}                                # lazy init separator to skip first
   END {for(k in f2) print k,f2[k],f3[k]}' file |   # iterate over keys and print
  column -t                                         # pretty print


10013  97,196,61,1559  1503384,1506234,1507385,1508385
10014  1726,960        1514507,1519162
10015  1920,124,77     1545535,1548915,1550284
```

note the output order is not guaranteed, but you can sort by the first field.

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution (assuming that the input lines are already sorted):

```
awk '!a[$1]++{ if ("f2" in b) { print f1, b["f2"], b["f3"]; delete b } }
     { 
         f1=$1; 
         b["f2"]=(b["f2"]!=""? b["f2"]",":"")$2; 
         b["f3"]=(b["f3"]!=""? b["f3"]",":"")$3 
     }
     END{ print f1, b["f2"], b["f3"] }' OFS='\t file
```

- `delete b` - with this action we'll prevent the array `b` from holding all values during the processing (saving memory). It will be cleared on each unique 1st field value

---

The output:

```
10013   97,196,61,1559  1503384,1506234,1507385,1508385
10014   1726,960    1514507,1519162
10015   1920,124,77 1545535,1548915,1550284
```